# Interacting with canvas rectangles by click event

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with canavas rectangles interaction in js. I want the user to choose rectangles from many rectangles drawn and put them in the order he want.

like : click=1 => print 1 on the rectangle where he clicked
       click=2 => print 2 on the rectangle where he clicked
       .
       .
       so on

I have succeded  to do the incrementation part but what i want is when the user re-click on on one of rectangles  the number disapears and the rest of rectangles must be decreased:
ex: if i click on rec 3: the rect 3 will be empty and 4 became 3, 5 become 3 and so on.

Here is the link to my code: [**JSFddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/haiballa/HUC2x/3/)

part of code where i'm having issues:

last part:

from "// Add event listener for `click` events" to the end

nb_vert: nuber of green rectangles

Comment: Your code has grown too big. You need to refactor it. define a rect class, break down functions into smaller ones, avoid globals and pack parameters within a small number of objects, rename things, tidy-up, comment, use english not french since you use S.O.,  ..., and all will work just fine. Because even if you succeed to fix this issue, you'll bump into another one very soon with such a code base.

Comment: thanks a lot.. your advice really helped me and my code runs correctly now.